# Spring Kafka disabling listening from a list of topics

Tags: spring-boot, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, spring-kafka

We use spring kafka configuration to receive messages from upstream systems.
We have java configuration for topic configuration

```
@Bean(id="firstcontainer")
protected ConcurrentMessageListenerContainer createContainerInstance(...) {
//topics addition
}


@Bean(id="secondcontainer")
protected ConcurrentMessageListenerContainer createContainerInstance(...) {
//topics addition
}


@KafkaListener(firstcontainer)
public void listenerFirst(){

}

@KafkaListener(secondcontainer)
public void listenerSecond(){

}
```

This code works perfectly fine as we have seperate containerfactory.
Now we have requirement to spin up mulitple instances of this application where one instance will listen to firstContainer and secondContainer will be disabled

And For second instance, it will only enable secondContainer and disable firstContainer.
Can someone help to understand if it is possible to disable listening from a topic(list of topics)?

Answer (score 0):

1. Your two instances (or many) can be identical and accept topic list from the external configuration. The `@KafkaListener` allows to do that.
2. There is Spring `@Profile` functionality, if you still want to keep several beans in your application. This way you should sever your `@KafkaListener` method to different classes and mark their component with an appropriate `@Profile`, which, again, can be activated externally.
3. The Apache Kafka has a concept as `Consumer Group` meaning that all consumers in the same group are joining to the broker, but only one of them will consume records from single partition in the topic. This way independently of the number of instances of your application you still will have a consistency because there is nothing to worry about duplicates in case of proper Kafka groups usage.